# How do I set up initialization code for Wolfram Workbench MUnit tests?

Tags: workbench, testing-and-verification

Say I have a couple of tests like the following:

```
Test[
    g[f[10]],
    100,
    TestID -> "Test-1-g"
]

Test[
    h[f[10]],
    200,
    TestID -> "Test-2-h"
]
```

Further, assume that `f[10]` is not cheap.  So I would like to initialize it as an environment variable for this suite of tests.  What is the correct way to do this in MUnit?  I cannot seem to find any documentation on the [official page](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/tester/tester.html) for an initialization function.

Comment: Never mind!  I think just defining a variable at the top of the file, like `a = f[10];` works fine!  I just thought that everything in a `.mt` file had to be inside a `Test*` function of some kind.

Comment: [read this](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/tester/childtests.html)

Comment: @molekyla777 Post it as an answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: @Shredderroy I have removed your comment in your question to close it. I think it is a valid and good question and someone else might stumble upon the same issue at some point. I asked molekyla777 to post an answer. If he doesn't, feel free to do it yourself and include his link to the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `Child Test Files` can help in your case. [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/tester/childtests.html)